# Adding multiple netcdf variables using nco tools

Tags: python, netcdf, nco

Is there a nco operator to create a new variable by adding multiple variables in a single netcdf file? I know you can use ncdiff to subtract, is there anything equaivalent operator for adding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [NCO's ncbo](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncbo-netCDF-Binary-Operator) function has subtraction, addition, multiplication, and division capabilities.  For adding in specific, you can alternatively call `ncadd`.  From the docs:

```
Definition: file_3 = file_1 + file_2
Alternate invocation: ncadd
op_typ key values: ‘add’, ‘+’, ‘addition’
Examples: ‘ncbo --op_typ=add 1.nc 2.nc 3.nc’, ‘ncadd 1.nc 2.nc 3.nc’
```

To add variables within a single netcdf file, you can use [ncap2](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncap2-netCDF-Arithmetic-Processor), e.g.

```
ncap2 -s 'var3=(var1+var2)' in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: thanks, ncbo seems to add multiple netcdf files. I want to add some variables within a single netcdf file

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to add variables within a single file.